# Build Decimal to Hexadecimal converter without the toString() JavaScript method

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex

I want to build a decimal to hexadecimal converter from scratch, the hard way. I wrote some code that works giving me the right numbers, but I'm struggling trying to convert these numbers into letters (A=10, B=11...).

What I want is to replace these numbers (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) with its equivalent (A, B, C, D, E, F) at my `result` array which is returning a list of each result given inside my `while` loop.

I tried to use the `replace()` method using this object
`var hexa = {'A':10, 'B':11, 'C':12, 'D':13, 'E':14, 'F':15};` but it looks like I can't use this method with lists.

```
var valor = 127;  // THIS IS THE DECIMAL NUMBER TO BE CONVERTED TO HEXADECIMAL
var result = [];

while (valor > 0) {
  result.push(valor%16);
  valor = Math.floor(valor/16);
}

result = result.reverse();

console.log(result);  // OUTPUTS [7,15]
```

Comment: I would use convStr = "0123456789ABCDEF" and just pick index from as convert[decLetter] == hexLetter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hexa` object keys and values should be reversed since you are looking for numbers to map to a character.

```
var hexa = { 10: 'A', 11: 'B', 12: 'C', 13: 'D', 14: 'E', 15: 'F' };
```

Then you can use [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to do the transformation.

```
result = result.map(value => value >= 10 ? hexa[value] : value);
```

To convert this result to hexadecimal number you can use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with empty character as the separator.

```
var hex = result.join('');
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var hexa = { 10: 'A', 11: 'B', 12: 'C', 13: 'D', 14: 'E', 15: 'F' };

var valor = 127;

var result = [];

while (valor > 0) {
  result.push(valor % 16);
  valor = Math.floor(valor / 16);
}

result = result.reverse();

result = result.map(value => value >= 10 ? hexa[value] : value);

console.log(result);

var hex = result.join('');

console.log("Hexadecimal number: " + hex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do probably something like this:

```
const digits = "0123456789abcdef";

const hex = val => {
  let result = "";

  while (val > 0) {
    result = digits[val % 16] + result;
    val = val >> 4;
  }

  return result;
}


console.log(hex(1234)); // 4d2
```

Comment: I'd use bitwise for the remainder too, `val & 15`

Answer (score 0):

You probably know that you need to transform each element of `result` to a hex digit, and then join them all together to form one single string. The function that does a transformation on each element of an array is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
result = result.map(x => transforms[x]);
```

where `transformDict` is an array containing all the transformations:

```
var transforms = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
```

Now `result` would be `['7', 'F']`, we just need to [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them!

```
console.log(result.join(''));
```

```js
var valor = 127;  // THIS IS THE DECIMAL NUMBER TO BE CONVERTED TO HEXADECIMAL
var reverseHexDigits = [];

while (valor > 0) {
  reverseHexDigits.push(valor%16);
  valor = Math.floor(valor/16);
}

var hexDigits = reverseHexDigits.reverse();
var transforms = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var result = hexDigits.map(x => transforms[x]).join('');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with the decimal values as key and the letters as value, unshift the value, to prevent to reverse at the end and take the part value as key for the object or if `undefined`, take the value directly.

At the end return a joined string.

```js
function getHex(decimal) {
  var hexa = { 10: 'A', 11: 'B', 12: 'C', 13: 'D', 14: 'D', 15: 'F' },
      result = [],
      part;

    while (decimal) {
        part = decimal % 16;
        result.unshift(hexa[part] || part);
        decimal = Math.floor(decimal / 16);
    }
    return result.join('');
}

console.log(getHex(127));
```